# OpenCL User Events / Cant Release Objects?

Tags: opencl

> NOTE:  Enqueued commands that specify user events in the
>   `event_wait_list` argument of  `clEnqueue***` commands must ensure that
>   the status of these user events being waited on are set  using
>   `clSetUserEventStatus` before any OpenCL APIs that release OpenCL
>   objects except for  event objects are called; otherwise the behavior
>   is undefined.

So if I have a user event being waited on in queue, I can't call release on any OpenCL object?

This seems like a strange requirement?  What is the purpose of it?  Or, why is it so?

The example they give is:

```
ev1 = clCreateUserEvent(ctx, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cq, buf1, CL_FALSE, ..., 1, &ev1, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cq, buf2, CL_FALSE,...);
clReleaseMemObject(buf2); // <--- UNDEFINED
clSetUserEventStatus(ev1, CL_COMPLETE);
```

Which causes undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example that they give.

We have an in-order queue and we create a user event:

```
ev1 = clCreateUserEvent(ctx, NULL); // (1)
```

We then want to enqueue a write to a buffer, but we want it to wait for our event:

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cq, buf1, CL_FALSE, ..., 1, &ev1, NULL); // (2)
```

We want to write another buffer after the buffer in the previous one (which is waiting on our event):

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cq, buf2, CL_FALSE,...); // (3)
```

We release the buffer from the second `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` which hasn't gone through yet because we are still waiting for the user event.  In this case (4) happens before (3), so we don't know what will happen as the memory object is freed.

```
clReleaseMemObject(buf2); // <--- UNDEFINED // (4)
```

We finally complete our user event which causes (2) and (3) to occur after (4) has already completed.

```
clSetUserEventStatus(ev1, CL_COMPLETE); // (5)
```

Basically, performing computation this way can cause problems because `clReleaseMemObject` doesn't get inserted into the `clCommandQueue` and can break the dependencies we expect.

Comment: How is the situation you described any different for non-user events? (ie if ev1 was a system event)    If your answer is that it isn't different, than why is the requirement specific to user events?  I believe (correct me if I am wrong) but when you queue up an operation (such as a write buffer) it holds a reference to the buffer while it is in the queue, so even if you release it (decrement its reference count), it will stay alive until it isnt referenced in the queue anymore.